# Python continue looping over a list even when a connection error occurs

Tags: python, list, loops, exception

I am having the following structure in my script:

```
id_list = [1, 2, 3]
for id in id_list:
    data = get_data(id)
    meta = get_metadata(id)
    # If there is a response, continue:
    if((data.json()) and (data.json())['job_status']=='SUCCESS'):
        # Do stuff
    else:
        print('Id is not found')
```

Here is `get_data()` script:

```
def get_data(form_id):
    survey_found = False
    try:
        print("------- Getting data from Source. Please wait. -------\n")
        print("------- Getting data from Source. Please wait. -------\n", file=logfile)
        response.raise_for_status()
        print(response.content)
        survey_found = True
        return response
    except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError, snowCtx.connection.errors.Error, requests.exceptions.HTTPError) as e:
        print("******* Error from Source (GETTING DATA): *******\n"+ str(e)+" on form id: "+str(form_id))
        print("******* Error from Source (GETTING DATA): *******\n"+ str(e)+ str(e)+" on form id: "+str(form_id), file=logfile)
        survey_found = False
        return survey_found
```

I don't care about `get_meta()` as the condition is on `get_data()`

The problem is if the first `id` was not available the code will stop executing because the `except` part will throw an http error.

I need the script to continue over other IDs in the list.

Comment: Instead of handling exceptions in your `get_data`, you would do a `try-except` block in your loop around your call to `get_data`, and `continue` if an exception is raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id_list = [1, 2, 3]
for id in id_list:
    data = get_data(id)
    if isinstance(data, bool) and not data:
        print(f"skipping {id}...")
        continue
    meta = get_metadata(id)
    if((data.json()) and (data.json())['job_status']=='SUCCESS'):
        # Do stuff
    else:
        print('Id is not found')
```